# Expanding parent div's height to fit floated & unfloated child divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a parent div `#modal_share` with a defined height of `400px`. I want it to extent its height to contain all its child divs when a new child div which is originally hidden, becomes visible.

**Problem:** Right now, when a hidden child div `.modal_error_msg` becomes visible, some divs below this newly visible div gets pushed outside its parent div.

How can I make the parent div `#modal_share` expand its height to contain all the visible child divs?

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TEmGc/

**CSS**

```
#modal_share {
    width: 565px;
    height: 400px;
    position: relative;
    background: whiteSmoke;
    padding-top: 10px;      
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 16px #222;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 16px #222;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 16px #222;
    display: none;  
}

.modal_big_hline {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    border-top: 1px solid #CCC;
    float: left;
}

.modal_error_msg {
    width: auto;
    height: 15px;
    padding: 15px 25px;
    margin: 0px 25px;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #B79000;
    border: 1px solid #E7BD72;
    background: #FFF3A3;
    clear: both;
    display: none;
}


#modal_big_button_container {
    height: 14px;
    width: auto;
    margin: 10px 25px 0px 25px;
    clear: both;
}
```

**HTML Structure**

```
<div id="#modal_share">
    <div class="modal_error_msg"></div>
    <div class="modal_big_hline"></div>
    <div id="modal_big_button_container"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For parent div `#modal_share` declare `height` as `auto` then it will automatically adjust height based on child elements.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `modal_share's` height to auto:

```
#modal_share {
    width: 565px;
    height: auto; //<----
    position: relative;
    background: whiteSmoke;
    padding-top: 10px;        
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 16px #222;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 16px #222;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 16px #222; 
}
```

See Feedle http://jsfiddle.net/TEmGc/1/